# file.exe is not commonly downloaded and could be dangerous - Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, download, exe

On my PHP web site, I have a 'download area' where there's a select box and a download-button. First, the user chooses the file and then clicks 'download'.

The download button triggers a `window.location = "...... .exe"` command, which Google Chrome doesn't like at all:

[image: Google Chrome is afraid]

**Question**

- What's so 'dangerous' about this download method?
- How to correctly perform a download on client click on an HTML button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does apache2 use a different MIME type when redirecting?

It doesn't. `application/x-msdos-program` is a correct MIME type for `.exe` files.

> How can I correct this error without complicated workarounds such as manually enter a MIME type?

You can't. The error you're seeing in Chrome is displayed for all unfamiliar downloaded `.exe` files, regardless of their MIME type.

Comment: Maybe I've gone into the complete wrong direction, thinking the MIME type is to blame. I will edit my question.

Comment: You're still blaming the wrong things. The warning has nothing to do with how the download is triggered, and everything to do with the fact that it's a Windows executable that Chrome doesn't know is safe.

Comment: You're right. My analysis was pretty bad on this one, sorry. But I've never seen such warning in Google Chrome before! I can understand that my executable is not on this particular 'list' or so. I also can't afford a signature. But there are a lot of web sites where you can download files that doesn't cause such irritating messages in Google Chrome, right? Is there any way to fix this, whatsoever?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it with the following set of headers:

```
Cache-Control: max-age=864000
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="....zip"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Last-Modified: ...
Etag: ...
Content-Length: ...
```

Be extra observant of Content-Type, Cache-Control, Last-Modified and Etag which seemed to be the helpful headers for me.